# Stripe API parsing JSON objects

Tags: json, python-3.x, stripe-payments

I'm getting a bit confused when retrueving card information. I get the card data like this:

```
card_data = customer.sources.list(limit=3, object='card')
    card = card_data['data']
    print(card)
```

And this is what is printed:

```
[<Card card id=card_1DPKYtAuBx2mXUsrmQG0gHMz at 0x54d8420> JSON: {
  "address_city": null,
  "address_country": null,
  "address_line1": null,
  "address_line1_check": null,
  "address_line2": null,
  "address_state": null,
  "address_zip": "42424",
  "address_zip_check": "pass",
  "brand": "Visa",
  "country": "US",
  "customer": "cus_Dqyu8HKCIQnUIA",
  "cvc_check": "pass",
  "dynamic_last4": null,
  "exp_month": 4,
  "exp_year": 2024,
  "fingerprint": "TuMlU4wS6zLVngGc",
  "funding": "credit",
  "id": "card_1DPKYtAuBx2mXUsrmQG0gHMz",
  "last4": "4242",
  "metadata": {},
  "name": null,
  "object": "card",
  "tokenization_method": null
}]
```

I'm unable to parse this data as if it were normal json "card['id']". How do I go about getting data from the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `card` you got from `card = card_data['data']` is an array. You could get the id by `card[0]['id']`

Give it a try
Thanks